# Retrieve a completely hidden File

Tags: file, explorer

I found a unushual executable on my computer. Im able to run it when i call it from cmd. But folder and file contained in it are completely hidden. I attempted to copy the file with the COPY command from cmd but no sucess.
I have show invisible files enabled but the file wont show up.
Is there any way i can retrieve that file?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to copy it via command line? also what is the name of the file?

Comment: Wait what!!? You found an unusual executable and decided to RUN IT!!? I have to say. Be more cautious please

Comment: That the system couldnt find the file
but when i go to C:\Users\usr\Desktop\data\7qkr4Lt4.exe (data folder is invisible too) and type in the name it can be executed

Comment: How do you know it is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

File can be made visible by using cmd:
attrib -s -h filename
this takes system and hidden propertys away from the file